# Visual Basic 2D Array Crashes Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, multidimensional-array

I am using Visual Studio 2012 for creating a web application server with vb.net and asp.net. I once had 116 separate arrays all with 116 values. I'm realizing now that it would be easier to run the calculations that I want if I used one 2D array instead. My 2D array has 116 sections of 116 integers. As soon as I complete the array with "}", Visual Studio crashes and restarts.

Is there a size limit to 2D arrays? Is there a step that I'm missing? Thanks!

My code looks like:

```
Dim data(,) As Integer = {{0, 9, 5, 7, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 2, 4, 2, 5, 7, 4, 6, 5, 3, 5...etc}, _
                          {9, 0, 7, 6, 6, 2, 5, 8, 8, 1, 5, 1, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 3, 7...etc}, _
                          {5, 7, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 8, 5, 7, 8, 3, 5, 4...etc}, _
                          ................[112 more of this].......................
                          {5, 8, 5, 8, 7, 7, 9, 0, 7, 2, 4, 2, 5, 7, 4, 6, 5, 3, 7...etc}}
                                                                                         ^
                                                                        'This is where crash happens
```

**EDIT:** I've done some testing and it seems to break around 40 lines.

Comment: Do you have all the updates to VS2012 installed? There was a performance problem with literal declaration of large arrays, but that was fixed.

Comment: This sounds promising! However, I am using a campus computer so I cannot install an update. Is there an alternative to literal declaration?

Comment: Have you tried `Dim data(115,115) As Integer` and just assigning `data(0) = {0, 9, 5,...etc}` etc.? An alternative would be to put the array data in a CSV file and read it in.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should consider a matrix, or use a list(0f) 
[Creating 2-dimensional array with unlimited size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102579/creating-2-dimensional-array-with-unlimited-size)

Also, a possibility is a dictionary, though I'm not sure what you are doing so its hard to say. Maybe, tell us what you are using the data for?

Nice bit of explaination regarding generics, lists, collections, and arrays. As noted in the comment above, I think you should dimension your array properly array(115,115) as the case may be. Or ReDim Preseve as you discover the size 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/333038-arrays-and-collections-overview/

Comment: I am making a web application that compares arrays to other arrays. Each index in each array is the compatibility score that that array has with the other arrays. So, for example, index(3) of array 1 is the same value as index(1) of array 3. My application will use this data to find which indices pair has the highest integer sum. If I start with array0 and array4, my application would find which array has the highest sum value of index0 and index4 combined. I wish I was better at explaining, but I hope that helped.